# Cognito + Lambda – How correlate User Login Information with a PUT parameter?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-cognito

[image]I have the following application (see the attached image):
     - Sensor -> send data to Amazon RDS (mySQL)
     - User Interface -> React.js -> Lambda -> Access data in Amazon RDS (mySQL)

!

All the user authentication it is done using Cognito.
I have a table where I have the “sensor_id” and the “product_owner_id”, as shown the table below:

[image]

Nowadays, I have a function where I am correlating the “sensor_id” and “Product_owner_id”, passing a parameter throught a “PUT” method, where this parameter it is the “OWNER_ID”.

```
getList(){
    axios.put(proxyurl + url, {
        "owner": 2 //I need to correlate this parameter with the Cognito User information
    }).then(resp => data)
   })
```

My question is:

•   Are there any way to correlate the parameter in the PUT method with the user login information from Cognito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of the specifics, but what I've done before is to store the user's cognito identity pool id as the "product owner id" in your table above.  You'd also need the cognito user pool username (or sub) in either the database or the identity pool so that you can do a lookup with the identity id back to Cognito to get the user info.  If you have your lambda behind an API gateway and invoke with caller credentials, you should get this information in `context.identity`

It's a pain to setup, but once done it works well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I understood the part of adding the collumns of "identity pool id" and "username or sub" in my table from my database. 
I still don't understand the following:
- How can I access this information in my React application?
- Do I need to configure the Cognito User Identity?

Comment: So, when a user logs in to Cognito through your react app, you should have the identity stored in `AWS.config.credentials` (if you're using Amplify).  Using that, you can search for the record with that identity id, and it would return the rest of the record.  You probably want to set the user_identity field in the database as an index to avoid issues with scans.  Does that help?